# Caused by: org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: null Enclosed Exception: null:0 The URI on element <image> can't be opened because

Tags: batik

when we try to convert SVG using batik 1.7 below issue is coming

The URI on element  can't be opened because:
The URI can't be opened:

Comment: The URI on element <image> can't be opened because:
The URI can't be opened: